# How to use the return values of this function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, web

i have a function:

```
def get_vals
  #do something...
  #
  # 
  #

  return arr1, arr2, arr3
end
```

arr1, arr2, arr3 are arrays.

Now I want to use these in my action:

```
def juko
  results = article.get_vals
  puts results
  #
end
```

With the puts command, I checked, that i get the 3 Arrays back. But I can not access it.

I tried it so:

```
@data_array = results[:arr1]
@data_input = results[:arr2]
@pairs = results[:arr3]
```

I get the message: "no implicit conversion of symbol into integer"

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3):

`get_vals` returns you an array.

Hotfix:

```
@data_array, @data_input, @pairs = results
```

Or, cleaner approach (return a hash from `get_vals` method):

```
def get_vals
  #
  #
  #
  { data_array: arr1, data_input: arr2, pairs: arr3 }
end
```

Now:

```
@data_array = results[:data_array]
@data_input = results[:data_input]
@pairs = results[:pairs]
```